# Get count from two different table based on datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables:
local_transports
foreign_transports
both tables have id,entry_time

table a:

```
id---entry_time
==============================
1--2017-07-17 12:10:39
2--2017-04-17 12:10:39
3--2016-07-17 12:10:39
4--2016-05-17 12:10:39
5--2015-07-17 12:10:39
6--2015-07-17 12:10:39
7--2014-07-17 12:10:39
8--2014-06-17 12:10:39
```

table b:

```
id---entry_time
==============================
1--2017-07-17 12:10:39
2--2017-04-17 12:10:39
3--2016-07-17 12:10:39
4--2016-05-17 12:10:39
5--2015-07-17 12:10:39
6--2015-07-17 12:10:39
7--2014-07-17 12:10:39
8--2014-06-17 12:10:39
```

my fiscal year will be start from July 01 to June 30

what i want :

```
-----2014-15--------2015-16-----------2016-17
foreign--local---foreign--local------foreign--local
===============================================
3---5-------------5--6----------------4----10
```

i want to get fiscal-yearly count from entry date from both table. how can i get this in mysql?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Note that there are 184 days between June 30th and December 31st.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 0 AND entry_time >= '2014-07-01' AND
                    entry_time < '2015-07-01' THEN 1 END) AS foreign_2014,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 1 AND entry_time >= '2014-07-01' AND
                    entry_time < '2015-07-01' THEN 1 END) AS local_2014,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 0 AND entry_time >= '2015-07-01' AND
                    entry_time < '2016-07-01' THEN 1 END) AS foreign_2015,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 1 AND entry_time >= '2015-07-01' AND
                    entry_time < '2016-07-01' THEN 1 END) AS local_2015
    -- add more counts for other fiscal years here
FROM
(
    SELECT id, entry_time, 0 AS type    -- 0 is for foreign
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, entry_time, 1            -- 1 is for local
    FROM tableB
) t;
```

This answers uses a union trick to bring both the local and foreign data into a single table.  We assign a status, 0 for foreign and 1 for local, in the process.  Then, we use `CASE` expressions to count records for each year and status.

Note that I assume here that the A and B tables contain the foreign anf local data, respectively.  If I have it backwards, then switch the status in my query.